# Write numbers everytime user enters new number

Tags: c#

At the moment I have following method:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter magical number");
        string input = "";
        int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if(number > 0){
            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}, ", i);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Pick another number");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Wow that number is too low for me!");
        }
    }
}
```

On the first run everything works as it should, but when the user enters new number the method stops. How I can prevent this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need some kind of flow control mechanism (e.g. a `for` loop).

Comment: After this line: `input = Console.ReadLine();` what exactly are you expecting to happen and why?  Are you asking how to write a loop?  If so, keep going on whatever tutorial(s) you're following, they will cover loops pretty soon.

Comment: What kind of numbers do you want to display? Numbers from 1 to number user gave? Or all the previous numbers entered by user?

Comment: I am wondering why a 3k user may ask such a question that seems just need a loop :-( Is there something missing?

Comment: @David I am stuck in a loop at the moment :D. LukaszBalazy - the current number entered by the user.

Comment: @Sasha: What "loop" are you "stuck in"?  Show you attempt at writing a loop, describe what is happening and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On the first run everything works as it should, but when the user
>   enters new number the method stops. How I can prevent this?

By using a loop instead of an `if`. You should also use `int.TryParse` to handle invalid input:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter magical number or enter exit to stop");
    string enteredNumber = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim();
    if ("exit".Equals(enteredNumber, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        break; 
    }

    bool valid = int.TryParse(enteredNumber, out int number);
    while (!valid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid integer");
        valid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine()?.Trim(), out number);
    }

    if (number > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(1, number)));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wow that number is too low for me!");
    }
} while (true);
```

I have also fixed the problem with the last comma at the end by using `string.Join`.

Answer (score 2):

Do not put *everything* into a *single* `Main`, *extract methods*:

```
private static int? ReadInteger(string title) {
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
    Console.WriteLine("Please, input integer value or \"quit\"");
  else
    Console.WriteLine($"{title}. Print \"quit\" to exit.");

  while (true) {
    string value = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

    if (string.Equals(value, "quit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      return null;
    else if (int.TryParse(value, out int result))
      return result;

    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the format is incorrect. Please, try again.");
  }
}

private static void Report(int number) {
  Console.WriteLine(number <= 0 
    ? "Wow that number is too low for me!"
    : String.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(1, number)));
}
```

Now, let's implement a simple `Main` method:

```
public static void Main() {
  // Just a simple "for" loop:
  //  - start with "Please enter magical number"
  //  - keep on until user puts "quit"
  //  - ask "Pick another number" for another numbers  
  for (int? value = ReadInteger("Please enter magical number");
       value.HasValue;
       value = ReadInteger("Pick another number") {
    Report(value.Value);
  }
}
```